# Find the parameter $m$ such that the number always be perfect square.

Tags: polynomials

I have to find the values of the parameter $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that the polynomial $(x-1)(x+3)(x-4)(x-8)+m$ is always a square for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may notice that:
$$ (x+3)(x-1)(x-4)(x-8) = (x^2-5x-10)^2-196 = (x^2-5x-24)(x^2-5x+4) $$
so the only value of $m$ for which $(x+3)(x-1)(x-4)(x-8)+m$ is always a square for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ is $m=\color{red}{196}=14^2$.

Comment: This solution implicitly uses the fact that $x^2 + a$ is square for all integers $x$ and only if $a = 0$.   This needs a proof, although it's easy: $a^2 + a$ is not square because it's between the consecutive squares $a^2$ and $(a+1)^2$.  (Note this holds even if $a$ is negative.)

Comment: @MichaelLugo: sure, but that is trivial. Squares form a convex set, hence only a finite number of different squares may be at a finite distance apart.